# How does Mathematica determine if a multivariate polynomial is absolutely irreducibile?

Tags: polynomials, implementation-details, reference-request

I am working with a collection of multivariate polynomials over **Q** in 5 or more indeterminates, all of which are irreducible over **Q**. However, after testing their absolute irreducibility via

```
IrreduciblePolynomialQ[poly,Extension->All],
```

some turn out to be absolutely irreducible, and some are not. What is the algorithm used by Mathematica (I'm using V12.0) to test absolute irreducibility?

I am aware of several papers that work with uni- and bivariate polynomials, and the paper "Fast Absolute Irreducibility Testing via Newton Polytopes" of Gao and Lauder which works with general multivariate polynomials, but unsure if this is what Mathematica is using.

Comment: You are testing irreducibility for polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ but `Extension->All` is for polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: @flinty, yes, that's the entire point of the question. I want to know why some polynomials irreducible over **Q** are absolutely irreducible, and some are not.

Comment: Are you asking that in general? Some multivariate polynomials are irreducible in $\mathbb{C}$ - it's a fact of life and worth discussing on Math S.E. If they're irreducible in $\mathbb{C}$ then surely they're irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$? Or have you encountered bugged examples where _Mathematica_ returns `True` because it's not able to prove there are no factors even when you know they exist and that's why you want to know the algorithm? If so, I've not found anything with spelunking `IrreduciblePolynomialQ` or `PolynomialReduce` and it's likely proprietary info.

Comment: @flinty I'm not sure what your concern is. I have certain polynomials that I know are irreducible over **Q**, however I am interested in their absolute irreducibility because that implies e.g. that their Newton polytopes are integrally indecomposable. I want to know how Mathematica determines absolute irreducibility because (1) I want to be sure that the answer returned is correct, and (2) so that I can find the property that distinguishes between the absolutely irreducible and reducible polynomials within the set of polynomials that I'm working with.

Comment: On my machine Mathematica can't factorize the polynomials in question, but it is able to tell if they're absolutely irreducible or not within minutes, so it is basing that decision on something that is not a factor count. I'm not certain that it's Gao-Lauder's algorithm because that, in my case, requires a computation of $\geq 5$-d convex hulls, which as far as I know Mathematica can't do but instead has to call an external program like qhull.